# Disable/enable a given path from the PATH environment variable

Tags: windows-7, gui

I am looking for a program for Microsoft Windows 7 that lets the user disables/enables a given path from the PATH environment variable in a convenient way through a GUI. [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about) is great to manage the PATH environment variable but it doesn't have this option to my knowledge (can only add/remove a path).

[image]

The feature would be somehow similar to CCleaner's feature to disable/enable a given program at startup:

[image]

Comment: A related question, for Windows 10: [GUI editor for Windows Environment Variables](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/28408/903)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: `Path Manager` does not work well at all ->
https://superuser.com/questions/891899/issue-when-disabling-a-path-using-path-manager/892798#892798

How about [PATH Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pathmanager/)
The screenshot shows an "active" column.

[image]

Comment: Did you use that software? Did you like it? What were your experiences? Does that "active" column do what you think it does?

Comment: Thanks Jack, the program looks perfect but unfortunately whenever I enable/disable a path I have to either restart the computer, or more simply to go to the he small and inconvenient Windows edit box and click OK there for the change to be taken into account (http://superuser.com/q/891899/116475) :/

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging I did still not find a *program* which does what you want. However, you could create a PowerScript for your purpose. This can be used as starting point:

```
#requires -version 2

param(
    [string] $AddedFolder,
    [bool] $ApplyImmediately = $true
)

$environmentRegistryKey = 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'

$oldPath = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $environmentRegistryKey -Name PATH).Path

# See if a new folder has been supplied.

if (!$AddedFolder)
{
    Write-Warning 'No Folder Supplied. $ENV:PATH Unchanged'
    return
}

if ($ENV:PATH | Select-String -SimpleMatch $AddedFolder)
{
    Write-Warning 'Folder already within $ENV:PATH'
    return
}

$newPath = $oldPath + ’;’ + $AddedFolder

Set-ItemProperty -Path $environmentRegistryKey -Name PATH -Value $newPath

if ($ApplyImmediately)
{
    if (-not ("Win32.NativeMethods" -as [Type]))
    {
        # import sendmessagetimeout from win32
        Add-Type -Namespace Win32 -Name NativeMethods -MemberDefinition @"
   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
   public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
       IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, UIntPtr wParam, string lParam,
       uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, out UIntPtr lpdwResult);
"@
    }

    $HWND_BROADCAST = [IntPtr] 0xffff;
    $WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1a;
    $result = [UIntPtr]::Zero

    # notify all windows of environment block change
    [Win32.Nativemethods]::SendMessageTimeout($HWND_BROADCAST, $WM_SETTINGCHANGE, [UIntPtr]::Zero, "Environment", 2, 5000, [ref] $result);
}
```

Source: http://poshcode.org/3537