# GUI editor for Windows Environment Variables

Tags: windows, gratis, gui

I'm looking for a simple tool that can edit my environment variables instead of having to use the default variable editor windows includes. I would like the editor to meet these requirements:

- Compatible with Windows 10
- Has a GUI interface (displays environment variables in a list)
- Can add, remove, or edit environment variables
- Gratis
- Ability to edit both the user and the system environment variables

Comment: Maybe in Windows 42 they'll have a decent built-in environment variable editor... anyway, related: [Disable/enable a given path from the PATH environment variable](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18073/903)

Answer (score 6):

Here is another environment variable editor and I'm using this one currently. It basically has all the functions and abilities of Path Editor from CodePlex, and much more. It meets all my requirements including being compatible with Windows 10 (Their website is only updated to Windows 8 but I've been using this with no problems on my Windows 10 system) and it is also gratis. It has added features such as an editable tree view, more information provided on variables, backup and restore support (to registry files), error checking, supports multiple languages, can accept command line parameters to modify environment variables, and more. Basically, if you're looking for software that has quite a few tools built into it, choose this one.

## [Rapid Environment Editor](https://www.rapidee.com/en/about)

> Rapid Environment Editor (RapidEE) is an environment variables editor. It includes an easy to use GUI and replaces the small and inconvenient Windows edit box. RapidEE 8.x supports Windows XP, 2003, Vista, 2008, Windows 7 & Windows 8 (including 64-bit versions). If you still use Windows NT or 2000, then use version 6.1. For Windows 9x or ME use version 2.1.
>
> [image: Rapid Environment Editor Screenshot]

Comment: I use RapidEE on Windows 7, works great there as well!

Answer (score 4):

There's two that I've used, here's one called PathEditor. It meets all my requirements including being compatible with Windows 10 and being gratis. It has a pretty simple interface, just two sections - one with the user environment variables and another with the system environment variables. Any user can load the program without needing an admin unless they need to make changes to the system variables. It has a few basic functions, add, remove, & edit environment variables as well as being able to reorder them. I recommend this one if your just looking for a simple & quick way to edit variables.

## [Path Editor](https://patheditor2.codeplex.com/)

> Edit PATH environment on Windows conveniently
>
> The default environment editor is not great at editing PATH if there are lot of entries and many of them are similar looking.
>
> 1. Implemented using Win32, Does not depend on MFC or .NET
> 2. Missing folders are highlighted with different icon.
> 3. To edit System PATH, offers to be launched with elevated admin privilege, similar to "Run as Administrator"
> 4. Double clicking any path entry attempts to open in Windows Explorer.
>
> [image: Path Editor Screenshot]]